# Which alternatives does Motif 2.3.8 has for virtual desktop?

Tags: c, x11, motif

I have read that MWM had WSM in the past, and that is included in the demos/programs folder in the source code for 2.3.8.

However, there is a note stating that the functionality to support was removed in 2.1.

As Motif is quite a legacy toolkit now the information available on this is obviously limited, I am wondering if somebody would still now (or remember from past days) which are the options to implement that kind of functionality in Motif.

I know such functionality is included in CDE which is now open sourced, but I do not like CDE.

Comment: You could try to find if LessTif (an open-.source clone of Motif) is available and implements the feature you need. It's *mostly* source compatible with Motif.

Comment: But then it would not be Motif

Comment: But why do you need Motif to begin with? Like you said, it's "quite a legacy toolkit", and there are many window-managers (old and new) that have virtual desktops. In the 1990's it was one of the main selling-points of window managers to have it.

Comment: I do not "need" Motif, I just like to use it.

Comment: Have you tried looking for other Motif window managers, like https://fastestcode.org/emwm.html?

Comment: Or perhaps look at more modern environments with a Motif theme or skin? Because frankly, Motif is a dead-end, it will never get new features (unless you add them yourself) and will never be maintained or have security problems fixed. The longer you wait to switch to something else, the worse it will get.

Comment: Some people drive vintage cars for no practical reason (they are expensive, difficult to find spare parts and less safe to drive than modern cars), consider it something like that.

Comment: Fair enough. On the other hand vintage car enthusiasts usually work on their cars themselves... ;)